# In solr, I want to know id "587" is in what position?

Tags: solr

Solr, I have document data, with uniqueKey field "id" in schema.xml

I just want to know **what position id "587" is in document** in all documents with sort,**return i**;

Can someone know what I mean?

Can someone help me?

**2012-6-4 11:26 update**

data example:search result [5,8,1,9,12,6,7,........] ids form solr document

How to know id=9 index/position in the result?

Comment: Don't understand the question. Perhaps provide an example? Each document in Solr index has an id. One would normally sort the result set if you would interested in where a document is positioned. This restriction/feature is similiar to retrieving data from a SQL database.

Comment: @@Mark O'Connor see my 2012-6-4 11:26 update